# Trigger mysql multi tabla

Tags: mysql

estoy incursionando en el mundo de los triggers, ya tengo dominio (considero que avanzado) en la elaboración de consultas (select) incluso anidadas.. mi intención es esta:

Acabo de crear una tabla (tabla 3),la cual necesito llenar (antes o después)  de actualizar el valor de un campo de la "tabla 1".
El tema es que los datos para llenar la "tabla 3" son el resultado de un select con datos relacionados de la "tabla1" y "tabla2".
Probé el trigger aplicado sobre una tabla y lleno la otra tal cual necesitaba con el resultado del select (usando new.campo) pero funcionó con un select sencillo (sin left join)..
Necesito poder llenar la "tabla 3" con los valores new del select relacionado con el left join  y los valores de los campos de las tabla1 tabla2...
adjunto un ejemplo con nombres genéricos para tratar de explicarlo

```
*****CREATE TRIGGER nombre_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON tabla1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
insert into tabla3 (campo1,campo2,campo3,campo4)
select
new.tabla1.campo1,
new.tabla1.campo2,
new.tabla2.campo1,
new.tabla2.campo2
from tabla1
left tabla2 on (tabla1.campo1=tabla2.campo1)
where new.tabla1.campo1=condicion
END*****
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! no existe new sobre tabla dos, porque el new trae los nuevos valores de la tabla que estas llenando, no de otras tablas.. que valores querias de la otra tabla??? quien los llena? en que caso? tal vez, no necesitas un trigger para este caso... seria raro...